# Transferring large files using WCF and ASP.NET web forms

Tags: asp.net, wcf, streaming, large-files

I'm trying to upload large files (upto 200MB) via ASP.NET web forms and store them in the database. I am able to upload large files using FileUpload control and I have setup a field in SQL Server as VarBinary(MAX) FileStream to store the files externally. I want to transfer the uploaded file using WCF service to the database and this is where I'm stuck. The only problem I have is when I try to stream the file from the code behind to the WCF service.

***Settings***:
**Client web.config in ASP.NET application**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"
                 sendTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:25333/FileTransfer.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" contract="FileTransfer.IFileTransfer"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Server web.config in WCF application**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Ward.POC1.FileStream">
        <endpoint address="ep1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceHost.IFileTransfer">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" 
                 sendTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I've used transferMode="Streamed" with the following contract definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileTransfer
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetFile(Guid fileId);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddFile(Stream fileStream);
}
```

Depending upon the change in the configuration settings I either get the following exception:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '24.20:31:23.6100000'.

or

> WCF The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Can anyone provide me with guidance on transferring uploaded large files between ASP.NET and another hosted application using WCF? I'm trying with Streaming. If anyone has elegant solution using binary array/chunking then its welcome too.

Comment: Files that large really need to be transferred using a protocol designed for file transfer, maybe FTP?

Comment: Web application is not meant to upload 1GB file. In the real world that will work really badly. If you want chunking you will have to write Silverlight component for that.

Comment: Large files for uploads are not common in my project. The users are willing to wait for the upload to complete and the only issue I have is while transferring the uploaded file to the WCF service host.

Comment: FTP is out of question because naive users of the application want a simple interface to just post the files.

Answer (score 0):

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=41ce408c159c69ea&sc=documents&id=41CE408C159C69EA%21321

I had similar issue. I Hosted WCF as WAS service and it worked fine. It has to do somewith with configuraton and I am not sure what it is?

Also, other interesting thing I noted is that if I keep the code in the code behind generated by WCF itself, it works. ( Mtom / stream configuration). But if I seperate the code behind(interface and implementation) to different directory, it fails. I ended up using the same code with WAS instead of IIS and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks dan. I altered few settings to allow large data transfer possible. And also threw in a windows stub application to load ridiculously large data files onto the database.